# split column by delimiter and deleting expanded column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, delimiter

I would like to know if there is a method to split a column by a delimiter and then removing the expanded column. Currently, this is what i am trying to do but it is not working as I wanted it to.

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'ID': [3009, 129,119,120,121 ],
  'temp': ['75.0~54.0','75.0~54.0','75.0~54.0','75.0~54.0','75.0~54.0'],
  'Prob': [1,1,0.8,0.8056,0.9]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)


       ID    Prob           temp
0    3009  1.0000       75.0~54.0
1     129  1.0000       75.0~54.0  
2     119  0.8000       75.0~54.0  
3     120  0.8056       75.0~54.0  
4     121  0.9000       75.0~54.0  
5     122  0.8050       75.0~54.0  

df['temp','temp2'] = = df['temp'].str.split('~', expand=True)
```

my goal is to split it by the delimiter and add a new column to the existing dataframe (df):

```
       ID    Prob        temp   temp2
0    3009  1.0000       75.0    54.0
1     129  1.0000       75.0    54.0  
2     119  0.8000       75.0    54.0  
3     120  0.8056       75.0    54.0  
4     121  0.9000       75.0    54.0  
5     122  0.8050       75.0    54.0
```

So that i can drop the temp2 column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index the split (that way, you don't have to deal with the `temp2` column):

```
df['temp'] = df['temp'].str.split('~', expand=True)[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     ID  temp    Prob
0  3009  75.0  1.0000
1   129  75.0  1.0000
2   119  75.0  0.8000
3   120  75.0  0.8056
4   121  75.0  0.9000
```

Comment: Nice! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `str.split()` and then use `.drop()` if you wish to remove the column from the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'ID': [3009, 129,119,120,121 ],
  'temp': ['75.0~54.0','75.0~54.0','75.0~54.0','75.0~54.0','75.0~54.0'],
  'Prob': [1,1,0.8,0.8056,0.9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['temp~'] = df['temp'].str.split('~')
df['temp_1'] = df['temp~'].str.get(0)
df = df.drop(columns=['temp~'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     ID       temp    Prob temp_1
0  3009  75.0~54.0  1.0000   75.0
1   129  75.0~54.0  1.0000   75.0
2   119  75.0~54.0  0.8000   75.0
3   120  75.0~54.0  0.8056   75.0
4   121  75.0~54.0  0.9000   75.0
```